# Weird high pitch grinding noise coming from car when starting/moving?

Tags: honda, starting, oil, transmission

I have a 2013 Honda Accord and had this weird high pitched grinding noise coming from the front. It is much more at cold starts and makes this noise regardless whether I am stopped, moving or braking.

The noise stops when the car up to temperature and is no longer noticeable. Transmissions shifts fine and had the fluid changed months ago. However, I did notice that when I changed my oil, the sound stopped for a couple of weeks and came back again. Is it low on oil (no lights came on) or could it be burning oil (no signs of it yet)

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is low on oil - as you ask that question...

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it is not low on oil. It seems a fresh oil change temporarily fixes it

Comment: More than likely it is an accessory on the drive belt, remove the drive belt and start it, if the noise is gone then look for something the drive belt turns as the culprit, it could be a power steering pump, alternator , AC compressor or idler pulley. Do not drive the car without the drive belt.

Comment: Okay I'll replace drive belt but why does the sound disappear when I change the oil? weird........